# Not able to Login with third party login providers (Google) in Google Chrome (Latest Version) browser MVC5 using Owin

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, google-signin, third-party-cookies

In **google chrome latest version 85** I am not able to use login service of third party providers Like (Google) but perfectly running on Firefox and other browsers.

**Test Case** 
After giving permission using Google Outh2.0 it redirect to singin-google with all details like state scope and all. But then it trying to `.AspNet.ExternalCookies` something but in Google chrome it is not created and it fails to login and generate callback with Error=**Access_Denied** 
But on other hand with different browser like Mozilla same code works and user able to logged in.

Further I looked for release notes for chrome and yes they depreciated features related to cookies but not able to handle in application.

If any one facing same issue or has any idea how to deal with this plz reply.

I am using latest version of Owin including Microsoft.Owin.Security and Google as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome implements samesite cookies with Lax option by default. But other browser yet to implements.

I got solution on microsoft website where we are explicitly setting cookies samesite=none for chrome browser and passing empty for other browser. 

For ASP.NET 4.7.2 with Microsoft.Owin 4.1.0 agent sniffing can be implemented using ICookieManager

Full code you can find [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/)